# Update ListView in ArrayAdapter when a row button clicked

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, adapter

I have a class OwnAdapter which extends the  ArrayAdapter.
Data to it is passed in a arrayList.
There is a custom layout contaning 2 TextViews and 2 Buttons.
I have defined the onClick actions on the buttons in the getView method of the adapter itself.
When the button of the rows are clicked there are some changes made to the database.Now I am not getting how to update the listview when either of the 2 buttons are clicked and show the new data.

```
bAttend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                //works fine
                upDateAttend(position);

                //code for updating view-What to add here?
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
    });
```

Comment: use notifyDataSetChanged(); after each change made.

Comment: Yes using yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); Make sure you update Your arraylist size as well

Comment: @teckwei arraylist size is not changing,but the contents of one of the row is being changed

Comment: @maharith-aditya-s-s I tried notifyDataSetChanged(); ,but it didn't had any effect.

Comment: @srk20 Can You show your button click listener code here so that it will be easy to tell whats the issue

Comment: @srk20 is your data getting updated and have you checked the list

Comment: @srk20 If  //works fine
                 upDateAttend(position); then put notifyDataSetChanged after Updating the data in list.

Answer (score 0):

after updating your arraylist make this line 
youradapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
if you updating the arraylist in the adpater just add notifyDataSetChanged();
see this link ,talk about recyclerview but will help you 
https://guides.codepath.com/android/using-the-recyclerview#notifying-the-adapter